# pagination and react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I am trying react-bootstrap.

I want to paginate like that with the component Pagination [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/pagination/) .

My code is :

```
<Pagination size="sm">
  <Pagination.First />
  <Pagination.Prev />
     { () => {for(let page=1;page<meta.last_page;page++){
        return <Pagination.Item>{page}</Pagination.Item>
     }}}
  <Pagination.Next />
  <Pagination.Last />
</Pagination>
```

I have this error :

**Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render**

How to loop to display the component Pagination ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looking at your syntax. you can't use a function to display an element. Basically all elements needs to be displayed directly without that outter `() =>`

```
  {items.map((item) => {
    return ...
  })}
```

Use this to replace your piece. Sometimes you might want to add a container to it, such as Fragment.

```
  <>
    ... // list of items
  </>
```

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation. But in the case of a loop "for". How to write this ?

Comment: essentially we are doing a loop, but `for` is not good here, since you need an array of items back. So if you need a `for`, you need to create an array object first. ex. `let a = []` and then go add item via `a.push(item)` and so forth.